# Securing Azure Active Directory B2C Access Tokens and Refresh Tokens

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-ad-b2c, refresh-token

I've come across so many articles explaining how tokens should be secured to prevent unauthorized attacks. The Microsoft documentation itself for msal.js specifies that tokens are stored in sessionStorage by default. Since localStorage and sessionStorage are both vulnerable to XSS attacks; what are some of the methods you guys have used to secure these tokens. Please keep in mind that I am hoping not to require my users to have to login frequently (I will need them to remain logged in for a chrome extension I'm building to go along with my web app).

I have created two separate projects; one for my apps api, and the other for my app client. I am using .net Core 2.2, and Angular 7. I have read articles where people say to use httponly cookies. My question in that respect is; how does that work with Azure Active Directory B2C? I'm just so confused, so if someone could clear up some stuff, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

So I've come to a slight conclusion that within an SPA (Single Page Application) usually an implicit grant is given. This means there is no refresh token provided, because there is no way to securely store it within the browser. Only an access token. Acccess token's are short-lived; therefore, should an attacker get a hold of, he can only perform damage for a specified amount of time and compromised access tokens are easier to detect and mitigate.

So my approach will be to use localStorage and to put some effort into preventing the common cross-site-scripting (XSS) attacks. As for the chrome extension google offers the 'chrome.identity' api that claims to securely store tokens as well as provide a secure way to fetch and refresh tokens. (src: https://www.informationsecuritybuzz.com/articles/security-and-privacy-best-practices-on-building-a-chrome-extension/)

So it would appear that via the chrome extension you could maintain a long-lived session, but due to SPA's none-existent security in the real of the browser any session would be limited to the lifetime of the access token itself. A user would be required to re-authenticate. If using a social login, this would be fairly seamless for the user.

If anyone sees any problems with what I've stated here, feel free to pitch in; otherwise I'll mark this question as answered for other's further reference as well as make myself available in the future for updates and questions regarding my experience moving forward.